# BreezeJS Entity keeps getting refreshed?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have a page with two panels. The first panel is where create and update happens, and the second panel is a list of stuff that I just added. Sort of like [this (below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFdnS.png). The second panel updates the list every X second.
[image]

Each list has an edit button that takes it back to the first panel. I pass the entity through the button's function and fill up the values in the edit panel. Here's the weird thing, when I try like say edit an entity in the list, an the interval happens to update the list, the entity gets refreshed and all my changes are never saved.

I tried just passing the id though the button then doing a get request for that particular entity and performing the edit, but the interval takes place and my changes are reverted.

I think my only option is to do `angular.copy(myEntity)` and do the edits from there, and then manually do the PUT request. Is there another way for the edited entity not to be affected by the interval aside from doing an `angular.copy()`? Pausing the interval while something is being edited is not an option, since client wants the list to update even when he's editing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep your data up to date by refreshing every few seconds, i recommend implementing a bool HasChanges() function in your controller. This will return true if the data has changed, and false if not. That way you can decide if you want to pull and refresh new data, or deffer it until your editing is done without overwriting your unsaved changes.